# How to adjust zoom size after map.locate function

Tags: geolocation, leaflet

I have a big problem. I am using leaflet javascript library to display openstreetmap. I would like to display a default size of 15, but its always end up showing zoom size 11. Basically, if I use map.locate function then it just displays the whole city with 30km diameter and my aim is display just 2km diameter. Interestingly, there is a way to increase the diameter(zoom size) from 12 to 10 or 8 but there is no way reducing zoom size :(

I am using map.locate to auto-locate user location on map but the zoom size is default 11 or it can be even bigger like 10,9, etc but its not possible to decrease zoom(diamter) size.

Here is my code:

```
function initMap() {
    map = L.map('map').setView(startingLocation, 15);
    map.on("locationfound", onLocationFound);
    map.on("locationerror", onLocationError);

     L.tileLayer('http://{s}.tile.cloudmade.com/BC9A493B41014CAABB98F0471D759707/997/256/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
                maxZoom: 18,
                attribution: 'Map data &copy; <a href="http://openstreetmap.org">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors, <a href="http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/2.0/">CC-BY-SA</a>, Imagery © <a href="http://cloudmade.com">CloudMade</a>'
            }).addTo(map);
}



  map.locate({
            setView: true,
            maxZoom: 16,
            enableHighAccuracy: true,
            timeout: 10000
        });

function onLocationFound(position) {
    marker.setLatLng(position.latlng);
    updateLocationWithRevGeocoding([{name: 'lat', value: position.latlng.lat}, {name: 'lon', value: position.latlng.lng}]);
}
```

And I am using p:remoteCommand(javascript call) for function updateLocationWithRevGeocoding to call updateLocationWithReverseGeocoding action from the backend bean.

```
 public void updateLocationWithReverseGeocoding() throws URISyntaxException, IOException {
        Map<String, String> params = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getRequestParameterMap();
        this.latitude = params.get("lat");
        this.longitude = params.get("lon");
        this.locationName = performReverseGeocoding(this.latitude, this.longitude);
        RequestContext.getCurrentInstance().execute("updateMarkerPopup(\"" + this.locationName + "\")");
    }
```

I see code below with zoom level 16, No matter how much i change this level, it stays the same. I just can increase diameter from 30km(Zoom size 11 to 10, 8 etc) but I am not able to decrease(diameter) zoom size :(

```
 private String performReverseGeocoding(String lat, String lon) throws URISyntaxException, ParseException, IOException {
        URIBuilder uriBuilder = new URIBuilder("http://nominatim.openstreetmap.org/reverse.php?format=json&zoom=16"); //I just removed original URL because of company proprietary.
        uriBuilder.setParameter("accept-language", "de"); // TODO externalize or parametrize
        uriBuilder.setParameter("lat", lat);
        uriBuilder.setParameter("lon", lon);
        //uriBuilder.setParameter("key", appKey);
        URI uri = uriBuilder.build();
        HttpGet request = new HttpGet(uri);
        HttpResponse httpResponse = this.httpClient.execute(request);
        Map<String, Object> jsonResponse = jsonMapper.readValue(EntityUtils.toString(httpResponse.getEntity(), "UTF-8"), Map.class);
        return jsonResponse.get("display_name").toString(); // TODO find something shorter and more informative
    }
```

I already debugged the javascript from firefox. Map zoom size automatically increases before the control enters into OnLocationFound call. I have an obligation to use map.locate, otherwise the map does not locate user to his location.

Comment: What does your `onLocationFound` function look like?

Comment: @nathansnider I just pasted all of the code on main